# How to connect to Oracle DB through python

Tags: python, oracle

I am trying to connect to Oracle through Python and trying to execute a few DDL & DML statements. Please help how it can be done

Comment: There are samples in https://github.com/oracle/python-cx_Oracle/tree/master/samples and a tutorial in https://github.com/oracle/python-cx_Oracle/tree/master/samples/tutorial

Answer (score 0):

a simple query

```
import cx_Oracle
con = cx_Oracle.connect('pythonhol/welcome@127.0.0.1/orcl')
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute('select * from departments order by department_id')
for result in cur:
    print result
cur.close()
con.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
import cx_Oracle
connection = cx_Oracle.connect("username", "password", "ip of your server"/"database name")

cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute("select * from table_name")

for row in cursor:
    print(row)
connection.close()
```